# Apt-get upgrade problem

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, aptitude

I've just tried to upgrade my system and got some very strange result: 665 packages skipped. What could be the reason? I have some old PHP installed to keep in sync with live servers but the rest of packages?

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following packages have been kept back:
  account-plugin-aim account-plugin-jabber account-plugin-salut
  account-plugin-yahoo accountsservice acpid alsa-utils anacron apparmor
  appmenu-qt5 apport apt apt-transport-https apt-utils aptdaemon aptitude
  aptitude-common apturl apturl-common argyll avahi-daemon bamfdaemon bluez
  brasero brasero-cdrkit brasero-common brltty bsdutils cabextract cheese
  cheese-common colord compiz compiz-core compiz-gnome compiz-plugins-default
  console-setup cpp cron cups cups-browsed cups-bsd cups-client
  cups-core-drivers cups-daemon cups-filters cups-filters-core-drivers curl
  dbus deja-dup dnsmasq dnsmasq-base dpkg empathy empathy-common eog evince
  evince-common evolution evolution-common evolution-data-server
  evolution-data-server-common evolution-data-server-online-accounts
  evolution-indicator evolution-plugins exo-utils file-roller fonts-thai-tlwg
  friendly-recovery g++ gcc gcc-4.9-base gcc-4.9-base:i386 gdb gdisk gdm geany
  geany-common gettext gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0 gir1.2-clutter-1.0
  gir1.2-cogl-1.0 gir1.2-coglpango-1.0 gir1.2-ebook-1.2
  gir1.2-ebookcontacts-1.2 gir1.2-edataserver-1.2 gir1.2-evince-3.0
  gir1.2-gck-1 gir1.2-gcr-3 gir1.2-gdata-0.0 gir1.2-gdm-1.0
  gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 gir1.2-gnomekeyring-1.0 gir1.2-goa-1.0
  gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 gir1.2-gtop-2.0 gir1.2-ibus-1.0
  gir1.2-mutter-3.0 gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0 gir1.2-nmgtk-1.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0
  gir1.2-secret-1 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0 glib-networking
  glib-networking:i386 glib-networking-common glib-networking-services
  gnome-backgrounds gnome-calculator gnome-color-manager gnome-contacts
  gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data gnome-disk-utility
  gnome-documents gnome-font-viewer gnome-keyring gnome-mahjongg gnome-mines
  gnome-online-accounts gnome-online-miners gnome-orca gnome-power-manager
  gnome-screensaver gnome-session gnome-session-bin gnome-session-common
  gnome-settings-daemon gnome-settings-daemon-schemas gnome-shell
  gnome-shell-common gnome-shell-extensions gnome-sudoku gnome-sushi
  gnome-system-monitor gnome-terminal gnome-terminal-data
  gnome-themes-standard gnome-themes-standard-data gnome-tweak-tool
  grilo-plugins-0.2 gsettings-desktop-schemas gstreamer1.0-clutter
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386 gvfs gvfs-backends
  gvfs-backends-goa gvfs-bin gvfs-common gvfs-daemons gvfs-fuse gvfs-libs
  hplip hplip-data hud humanity-icon-theme ibus ibus-pinyin icu-devtools
  ifupdown indicator-appmenu indicator-datetime indicator-keyboard
  init-system-helpers initscripts irqbalance isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common
  keyboard-configuration kmod lib32gcc1 libaacs0 libaccount-plugin-1.0-0
  libaccounts-qt5-1 libaccountsservice0 libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl
  libapparmor-perl libapt-pkg-perl libapt-pkg4.12 libatkmm-1.6-1 libatomic1
  libav-tools libbamf3-2 libbrasero-media3-1 libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6
  libc6:i386 libc6-dbg libc6-dev libc6-i386 libcheese-gtk23 libcheese7
  libchromaprint0 libclone-perl libcloog-isl4 libclutter-1.0-0
  libclutter-gst-2.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcolord-gtk1 libcolumbus1
  libcolumbus1-common libcompizconfig0 libcompress-raw-bzip2-perl
  libcompress-raw-lzma-perl libcompress-raw-zlib-perl libcups2 libcups2:i386
  libcupscgi1 libcupsimage2 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1 libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls
  libcwidget3 libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libdecoration0 libdirac-encoder0
  libebackend-1.2-7 libebook-1.2-14 libecal-1.2-16 libedata-book-1.2-20
  libedata-cal-1.2-23 libedataserver-1.2-18 libegl1-mesa libept1.4.12
  libevdocument3-4 libevolution libevview3-3 libexo-1-0 libfftw3-single3
  libfile-fcntllock-perl libfreerdp-plugins-standard libgail-3-0 libgarcon-1-0
  libgbm1 libgcc1 libgcc1:i386 libgcr-base-3-1 libgcr-ui-3-1 libgdm1
  libgexiv2-2 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libglibmm-2.4-1c2a
  libgnome-keyring-common libgnome-keyring0 libgnomevfs2-0 libgnutls-openssl27
  libgoa-1.0-0b libgoa-1.0-common libgoa-backend-1.0-1 libgomp1 libgpod-common
  libgpod4 libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:i386
  libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtkhtml-4.0-0 libgtkhtml-4.0-common
  libgtkhtml-editor-4.0-0 libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a libgtkmm-3.0-1
  libgtksourceview-3.0-1 libgweather-3-6 libhpmud0 libhtml-parser-perl libhud2
  libicu-dev libicu52 libimobiledevice4 libio-compress-lzma-perl
  libio-compress-perl libio-pty-perl libitm1 libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0
  libldap-2.4-2 libldb1 liblist-moreutils-perl libllvm3.4 libllvm3.6
  libllvm3.6:i386 liblocale-gettext-perl liblog-message-simple-perl
  libmm-glib0 libmtp-runtime libmtp9 libneon27-gnutls libnet-dns-perl
  libnet-libidn-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libnetaddr-ip-perl libnm-glib4
  libnm-gtk-common libnm-gtk0 libnm-util2 libnux-4.0-0 libnux-4.0-common
  libpam-modules libpam-modules-bin libpam-systemd libpangomm-1.4-1
  libperlio-gzip-perl libpolkit-backend-1-0 libpolkit-gobject-1-0
  libpoppler-glib8 libproxy1 libproxy1:i386 libproxy1-plugin-gsettings
  libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0
  libpulse0:i386 libpulsedsp libpurple0 libpython-stdlib libpython2.7
  libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libqpdf13 libqt4-dbus
  libqt4-dbus:i386 libqt4-declarative libqt4-declarative:i386 libqt4-designer
  libqt4-help libqt4-network libqt4-network:i386 libqt4-opengl
  libqt4-opengl:i386 libqt4-script libqt4-script:i386 libqt4-scripttools
  libqt4-sql libqt4-sql:i386 libqt4-sql-mysql:i386 libqt4-sql-sqlite
  libqt4-svg libqt4-test libqt4-xml libqt4-xml:i386 libqt4-xmlpatterns
  libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 libqt5core5a libqt5dbus5 libqt5feedback5 libqt5gui5
  libqt5multimedia5 libqt5network5 libqt5opengl5 libqt5organizer5
  libqt5positioning5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5qml-graphicaleffects libqt5qml5
  libqt5quick5 libqt5sensors5 libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite libqt5svg5
  libqt5test5 libqt5webkit5 libqt5webkit5-qmlwebkitplugin libqt5widgets5
  libqt5xml5 libqtcore4 libqtcore4:i386 libqtdbus4 libqtdbus4:i386 libqtgui4
  libqtgui4:i386 libquadmath0 libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer
  libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core
  libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-help-en-gb
  libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-impress libreoffice-l10n-en-gb
  libreoffice-l10n-en-za libreoffice-math libreoffice-pdfimport
  libreoffice-style-human libreoffice-style-tango libreoffice-writer
  librhythmbox-core8 libsane-hpaio libsecret-1-0 libsignon-extension1
  libsmbclient libsnmp30 libsocket6-perl libssh2-1 libstdc++6 libstdc++6:i386
  libsub-identify-perl libsub-name-perl libtag1-vanilla libtag1-vanilla:i386
  libtag1c2a libtag1c2a:i386 libterm-readkey-perl libtext-charwidth-perl
  libtext-iconv-perl libtext-soundex-perl libthunarx-2-0 libtimezonemap1
  libtirpc1 libtotem-plparser18 libtotem0 libtsan0 libudev1 libudev1:i386
  libunity-core-6.0-9 libunityvoice1 libusbmuxd2 libuuid-perl libva1 libvlc5
  libvncserver0 libwacom-common libwacom2 libwayland-egl1-mesa
  libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwhoopsie-preferences0 libwhoopsie0 libxapian22
  libxfce4ui-1-0 libxfce4ui-utils libxfce4util-bin libxml2 libxml2:i386
  libxslt1.1 libxslt1.1:i386 lightdm lighttpd linux-headers-generic lm-sensors
  lsb-base lshw mcp-account-manager-goa mcp-account-manager-uoa
  metacity-common modemmanager mount mountall mplayer2 mutter mutter-common
  mysql-common mysql-server mysql-workbench mysql-workbench-data nautilus
  nautilus-data network-manager network-manager-gnome network-manager-pptp
  network-manager-pptp-gnome nfs-common ntfs-3g nvidia-prime onboard orage
  parted perl perl-base perl-modules php-pear php5-cgi php5-cli php5-common
  php5-curl php5-dev php5-gd php5-mysql php5-tidy php5-xsl pidgin plymouth
  plymouth-label plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text poppler-utils ppp
  printer-driver-foo2zjs printer-driver-foo2zjs-common printer-driver-hpcups
  printer-driver-postscript-hp procps pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
  pulseaudio-module-x11 pulseaudio-utils python python-apt python-aptdaemon
  python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python-ldb python-lxml python-minimal
  python-paramiko python-pycurl python-requests python-samba
  python-twisted-core python-twisted-web python-urllib3 python-xapian
  python2.7 python2.7-minimal python3-apt python3-aptdaemon
  python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat python3-distupgrade
  python3-lxml python3-uno qdbus qpdf qtchooser qtdeclarative5-accounts-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-dialogs-plugin qtdeclarative5-localstorage-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-privatewidgets-plugin qtdeclarative5-qtfeedback-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-extras-browser-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin qtdeclarative5-window-plugin remmina
  remmina-common remmina-plugin-rdp remmina-plugin-vnc resolvconf rfkill
  rhythmbox rhythmbox-data rhythmbox-mozilla rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder
  rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist rhythmbox-plugins
  rpcbind rsyslog rtmpdump ruby samba-common samba-common-bin samba-libs
  seahorse shotwell shotwell-common signon-plugin-oauth2 signon-ui signond
  simple-scan smbclient spamassassin system-config-printer-common
  system-config-printer-gnome system-config-printer-udev systemd-shim
  telepathy-gabble telepathy-salut thunar thunar-data thunar-volman totem
  totem-common totem-plugins tracker tracker-extract tracker-miner-fs
  tracker-utils transmission-common transmission-gtk ubuntu-desktop
  ubuntu-drivers-common ubuntu-gnome-desktop ubuntu-gnome-wallpapers
  ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-mono ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk ubuntu-session ubuntu-standard ubuntu-wallpapers
  udev udisks2 ufw unattended-upgrades unity unity-asset-pool
  unity-control-center unity-control-center-signon unity-greeter
  unity-services unity-settings-daemon unity-voice-service unity-webapps-qml
  uno-libs3 upower upstart ure ureadahead usbmuxd util-linux
  util-linux-locales uuid-runtime vino vlc vlc-data vlc-nox vlc-plugin-notify
  vlc-plugin-pulse webapp-container webbrowser-app whoopsie
  whoopsie-preferences xdiagnose xfce4-appfinder xfce4-mixer xfce4-notifyd
  xfce4-panel xfce4-session xfce4-settings xfconf xfdesktop4 xfdesktop4-data
  xfwm4 xorg xserver-xephyr xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core
  xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-mouse
  xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse
  xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-cirrus
  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev xserver-xorg-video-mach64 xserver-xorg-video-mga
  xserver-xorg-video-openchrome xserver-xorg-video-qxl xserver-xorg-video-r128
  xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-s3 xserver-xorg-video-savage
  xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion xserver-xorg-video-tdfx
  xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware zeitgeist-core
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 665 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 2):

These skipped package can be upgrade using command:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If you want to know `upgrade` and `dist-upgrade` difference:

From [`apt-get` manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/apt-get.8):

```
upgrade
   upgrade is used to install the newest versions of all packages
   currently installed on the system from the sources enumerated in
   /etc/apt/sources.list. Packages currently installed with new
   versions available are retrieved and upgraded; under no
   circumstances are currently installed packages removed, or packages
   not already installed retrieved and installed. New versions of
   currently installed packages that cannot be upgraded without
   changing the install status of another package will be left at
   their current version. An update must be performed first so that
   apt-get knows that new versions of packages are available.

dist-upgrade
   dist-upgrade in addition to performing the function of upgrade,
   also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions
   of packages; apt-get has a "smart" conflict resolution system, and
   it will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the
   expense of less important ones if necessary. So, dist-upgrade
   command may remove some packages. The /etc/apt/sources.list file
   contains a list of locations from which to retrieve desired package
   files. See also apt_preferences(5) for a mechanism for overriding
   the general settings for individual packages.
```

NOTE: Please ensure `sources.list` has correct packages list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dist-upgrade` command that was mentioned by snoop, but that won't necessarily be the best idea... it can be rather dangerous because if have a wrong `sources.list` setting you end up with a broken Ubuntu. The command essentially upgrades your system to newer version, for example from 14.04 to 15.04.

It would be better to simply use `sudo apt-get install <packagename>`

So the command for you would be:

```
  sudo apt-get install account-plugin-aim account-plugin-jabber account-plugin-salut
  account-plugin-yahoo accountsservice acpid alsa-utils anacron apparmor
  appmenu-qt5 apport apt apt-transport-https apt-utils aptdaemon aptitude
  aptitude-common apturl apturl-common argyll avahi-daemon bamfdaemon bluez
  brasero brasero-cdrkit brasero-common brltty bsdutils cabextract cheese
  cheese-common colord compiz compiz-core compiz-gnome compiz-plugins-default
  console-setup cpp cron cups cups-browsed cups-bsd cups-client
  cups-core-drivers cups-daemon cups-filters cups-filters-core-drivers curl
  dbus deja-dup dnsmasq dnsmasq-base dpkg empathy empathy-common eog evince
  evince-common evolution evolution-common evolution-data-server
  evolution-data-server-common evolution-data-server-online-accounts
  evolution-indicator evolution-plugins exo-utils file-roller fonts-thai-tlwg
  friendly-recovery g++ gcc gcc-4.9-base gcc-4.9-base:i386 gdb gdisk gdm geany
  geany-common gettext gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0 gir1.2-clutter-1.0
  gir1.2-cogl-1.0 gir1.2-coglpango-1.0 gir1.2-ebook-1.2
  gir1.2-ebookcontacts-1.2 gir1.2-edataserver-1.2 gir1.2-evince-3.0
  gir1.2-gck-1 gir1.2-gcr-3 gir1.2-gdata-0.0 gir1.2-gdm-1.0
  gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 gir1.2-gnomekeyring-1.0 gir1.2-goa-1.0
  gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 gir1.2-gtop-2.0 gir1.2-ibus-1.0
  gir1.2-mutter-3.0 gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0 gir1.2-nmgtk-1.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0
  gir1.2-secret-1 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0 glib-networking
  glib-networking:i386 glib-networking-common glib-networking-services
  gnome-backgrounds gnome-calculator gnome-color-manager gnome-contacts
  gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data gnome-disk-utility
  gnome-documents gnome-font-viewer gnome-keyring gnome-mahjongg gnome-mines
  gnome-online-accounts gnome-online-miners gnome-orca gnome-power-manager
  gnome-screensaver gnome-session gnome-session-bin gnome-session-common
  gnome-settings-daemon gnome-settings-daemon-schemas gnome-shell
  gnome-shell-common gnome-shell-extensions gnome-sudoku gnome-sushi
  gnome-system-monitor gnome-terminal gnome-terminal-data
  gnome-themes-standard gnome-themes-standard-data gnome-tweak-tool
  grilo-plugins-0.2 gsettings-desktop-schemas gstreamer1.0-clutter
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386 gvfs gvfs-backends
  gvfs-backends-goa gvfs-bin gvfs-common gvfs-daemons gvfs-fuse gvfs-libs
  hplip hplip-data hud humanity-icon-theme ibus ibus-pinyin icu-devtools
  ifupdown indicator-appmenu indicator-datetime indicator-keyboard
  init-system-helpers initscripts irqbalance isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common
  keyboard-configuration kmod lib32gcc1 libaacs0 libaccount-plugin-1.0-0
  libaccounts-qt5-1 libaccountsservice0 libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl
  libapparmor-perl libapt-pkg-perl libapt-pkg4.12 libatkmm-1.6-1 libatomic1
  libav-tools libbamf3-2 libbrasero-media3-1 libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6
  libc6:i386 libc6-dbg libc6-dev libc6-i386 libcheese-gtk23 libcheese7
  libchromaprint0 libclone-perl libcloog-isl4 libclutter-1.0-0
  libclutter-gst-2.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcolord-gtk1 libcolumbus1
  libcolumbus1-common libcompizconfig0 libcompress-raw-bzip2-perl
  libcompress-raw-lzma-perl libcompress-raw-zlib-perl libcups2 libcups2:i386
  libcupscgi1 libcupsimage2 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1 libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls
  libcwidget3 libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libdecoration0 libdirac-encoder0
  libebackend-1.2-7 libebook-1.2-14 libecal-1.2-16 libedata-book-1.2-20
  libedata-cal-1.2-23 libedataserver-1.2-18 libegl1-mesa libept1.4.12
  libevdocument3-4 libevolution libevview3-3 libexo-1-0 libfftw3-single3
  libfile-fcntllock-perl libfreerdp-plugins-standard libgail-3-0 libgarcon-1-0
  libgbm1 libgcc1 libgcc1:i386 libgcr-base-3-1 libgcr-ui-3-1 libgdm1
  libgexiv2-2 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libglibmm-2.4-1c2a
  libgnome-keyring-common libgnome-keyring0 libgnomevfs2-0 libgnutls-openssl27
  libgoa-1.0-0b libgoa-1.0-common libgoa-backend-1.0-1 libgomp1 libgpod-common
  libgpod4 libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:i386
  libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtkhtml-4.0-0 libgtkhtml-4.0-common
  libgtkhtml-editor-4.0-0 libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a libgtkmm-3.0-1
  libgtksourceview-3.0-1 libgweather-3-6 libhpmud0 libhtml-parser-perl libhud2
  libicu-dev libicu52 libimobiledevice4 libio-compress-lzma-perl
  libio-compress-perl libio-pty-perl libitm1 libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0
  libldap-2.4-2 libldb1 liblist-moreutils-perl libllvm3.4 libllvm3.6
  libllvm3.6:i386 liblocale-gettext-perl liblog-message-simple-perl
  libmm-glib0 libmtp-runtime libmtp9 libneon27-gnutls libnet-dns-perl
  libnet-libidn-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libnetaddr-ip-perl libnm-glib4
  libnm-gtk-common libnm-gtk0 libnm-util2 libnux-4.0-0 libnux-4.0-common
  libpam-modules libpam-modules-bin libpam-systemd libpangomm-1.4-1
  libperlio-gzip-perl libpolkit-backend-1-0 libpolkit-gobject-1-0
  libpoppler-glib8 libproxy1 libproxy1:i386 libproxy1-plugin-gsettings
  libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0
  libpulse0:i386 libpulsedsp libpurple0 libpython-stdlib libpython2.7
  libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libqpdf13 libqt4-dbus
  libqt4-dbus:i386 libqt4-declarative libqt4-declarative:i386 libqt4-designer
  libqt4-help libqt4-network libqt4-network:i386 libqt4-opengl
  libqt4-opengl:i386 libqt4-script libqt4-script:i386 libqt4-scripttools
  libqt4-sql libqt4-sql:i386 libqt4-sql-mysql:i386 libqt4-sql-sqlite
  libqt4-svg libqt4-test libqt4-xml libqt4-xml:i386 libqt4-xmlpatterns
  libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 libqt5core5a libqt5dbus5 libqt5feedback5 libqt5gui5
  libqt5multimedia5 libqt5network5 libqt5opengl5 libqt5organizer5
  libqt5positioning5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5qml-graphicaleffects libqt5qml5
  libqt5quick5 libqt5sensors5 libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite libqt5svg5
  libqt5test5 libqt5webkit5 libqt5webkit5-qmlwebkitplugin libqt5widgets5
  libqt5xml5 libqtcore4 libqtcore4:i386 libqtdbus4 libqtdbus4:i386 libqtgui4
  libqtgui4:i386 libquadmath0 libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer
  libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core
  libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-help-en-gb
  libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-impress libreoffice-l10n-en-gb
  libreoffice-l10n-en-za libreoffice-math libreoffice-pdfimport
  libreoffice-style-human libreoffice-style-tango libreoffice-writer
  librhythmbox-core8 libsane-hpaio libsecret-1-0 libsignon-extension1
  libsmbclient libsnmp30 libsocket6-perl libssh2-1 libstdc++6 libstdc++6:i386
  libsub-identify-perl libsub-name-perl libtag1-vanilla libtag1-vanilla:i386
  libtag1c2a libtag1c2a:i386 libterm-readkey-perl libtext-charwidth-perl
  libtext-iconv-perl libtext-soundex-perl libthunarx-2-0 libtimezonemap1
  libtirpc1 libtotem-plparser18 libtotem0 libtsan0 libudev1 libudev1:i386
  libunity-core-6.0-9 libunityvoice1 libusbmuxd2 libuuid-perl libva1 libvlc5
  libvncserver0 libwacom-common libwacom2 libwayland-egl1-mesa
  libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwhoopsie-preferences0 libwhoopsie0 libxapian22
  libxfce4ui-1-0 libxfce4ui-utils libxfce4util-bin libxml2 libxml2:i386
  libxslt1.1 libxslt1.1:i386 lightdm lighttpd linux-headers-generic lm-sensors
  lsb-base lshw mcp-account-manager-goa mcp-account-manager-uoa
  metacity-common modemmanager mount mountall mplayer2 mutter mutter-common
  mysql-common mysql-server mysql-workbench mysql-workbench-data nautilus
  nautilus-data network-manager network-manager-gnome network-manager-pptp
  network-manager-pptp-gnome nfs-common ntfs-3g nvidia-prime onboard orage
  parted perl perl-base perl-modules php-pear php5-cgi php5-cli php5-common
  php5-curl php5-dev php5-gd php5-mysql php5-tidy php5-xsl pidgin plymouth
  plymouth-label plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text poppler-utils ppp
  printer-driver-foo2zjs printer-driver-foo2zjs-common printer-driver-hpcups
  printer-driver-postscript-hp procps pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
  pulseaudio-module-x11 pulseaudio-utils python python-apt python-aptdaemon
  python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python-ldb python-lxml python-minimal
  python-paramiko python-pycurl python-requests python-samba
  python-twisted-core python-twisted-web python-urllib3 python-xapian
  python2.7 python2.7-minimal python3-apt python3-aptdaemon
  python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat python3-distupgrade
  python3-lxml python3-uno qdbus qpdf qtchooser qtdeclarative5-accounts-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-dialogs-plugin qtdeclarative5-localstorage-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-privatewidgets-plugin qtdeclarative5-qtfeedback-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-extras-browser-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin qtdeclarative5-window-plugin remmina
  remmina-common remmina-plugin-rdp remmina-plugin-vnc resolvconf rfkill
  rhythmbox rhythmbox-data rhythmbox-mozilla rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder
  rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist rhythmbox-plugins
  rpcbind rsyslog rtmpdump ruby samba-common samba-common-bin samba-libs
  seahorse shotwell shotwell-common signon-plugin-oauth2 signon-ui signond
  simple-scan smbclient spamassassin system-config-printer-common
  system-config-printer-gnome system-config-printer-udev systemd-shim
  telepathy-gabble telepathy-salut thunar thunar-data thunar-volman totem
  totem-common totem-plugins tracker tracker-extract tracker-miner-fs
  tracker-utils transmission-common transmission-gtk ubuntu-desktop
  ubuntu-drivers-common ubuntu-gnome-desktop ubuntu-gnome-wallpapers
  ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-mono ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk ubuntu-session ubuntu-standard ubuntu-wallpapers
  udev udisks2 ufw unattended-upgrades unity unity-asset-pool
  unity-control-center unity-control-center-signon unity-greeter
  unity-services unity-settings-daemon unity-voice-service unity-webapps-qml
  uno-libs3 upower upstart ure ureadahead usbmuxd util-linux
  util-linux-locales uuid-runtime vino vlc vlc-data vlc-nox vlc-plugin-notify
  vlc-plugin-pulse webapp-container webbrowser-app whoopsie
  whoopsie-preferences xdiagnose xfce4-appfinder xfce4-mixer xfce4-notifyd
  xfce4-panel xfce4-session xfce4-settings xfconf xfdesktop4 xfdesktop4-data
  xfwm4 xorg xserver-xephyr xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core
  xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-mouse
  xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse
  xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-cirrus
  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev xserver-xorg-video-mach64 xserver-xorg-video-mga
  xserver-xorg-video-openchrome xserver-xorg-video-qxl xserver-xorg-video-r128
  xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-s3 xserver-xorg-video-savage
  xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion xserver-xorg-video-tdfx
  xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware zeitgeist-core
```

Comment: -1 This has the side effect of marking these packages as manually installed which is not an immediate problem but will make it much harder to remove former but now unneeded dependencies in the future.